# What is the purpose of each of the two Clipboard classes in .NET?

Tags: .net, clipboard

Why does .NET provide two Clipboard classes:

**System.Windows.Clipboard** and **System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard**?

Is there a significant difference between those classes?

Comment: Because one is used with Windows Forms and the other with WPF.

Comment: And why would I need two different classes in WPF in WinForms for the same functionality.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard came from net 1.1,  System.Windows.Clipboard came later net 3.5 + Silverlight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Windows.Clipboard` is used by WPF applications, whereas `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` is used for WinForms.

They do the same thing, it's just there twice so WPF applications don't need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, and vice versa.

Secondly, `System.Windows.Clipboard` came after `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`. `System.Windows.Clipboard` exists for other platforms that *can't* reference System.Windows.Forms, like [Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Ah, ok. that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

One is WPF and the other is Windows Forms. If you look at the MSDN pages, you'll see that [System.Windows.Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `PresentationCore.dll` assembly (that's WPF), the other [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly (that's, not surprisingly, windows forms).

They are both, essentially, just static wrappers around calls to the windows API (in user32.dll) to manipulate the clipboard. Use which ever one matches the technology you are using for your application. This avoids the need to import `System.Windows.Forms` into your WPF application just for the clipboard or else re-writing a bunch of pinvoke code to hit the API directly in your own code.